# Search wont show any result

Tags: search

i have very strange issue with my search, it wont show any result, and i have checked CA search service application and everything looks fine. there wasnt much information in logs.
Fetching app info failed: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException: The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check whether your web application is connected to Search Service Proxy https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/add-or-remove-a-service-application-connection-to-a-web-application

Answer (score 0):

Check if your serve has the Search Service Proxy or not.

If it exists then delete and create new.

If does not exist then create the new using below command.

```
$searchServiceApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -SearchApplication $searchServiceApp
```

Refer to below links for more details.

[Similar Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2888383/sharepoint-search-queries-fail-with-the-search-request-was-unable-to-c)

[Get SPServices configured](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spserviceinstance?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/remove-spserviceapplicationproxy?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Search Issue due to MasterPage](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d9b9bc9-fa5c-4919-8dc1-d2ceb6f7d99f/application-server-job-failed-for-service-instance?forum=sharepointsearch)

Comment: no luck, i have deleted the existing one and create a new one. still same issue

Comment: Can you provide the ULS logs ?
Also, delete the whole search service application and create new one. It may be possible that the current search service application is corrupted.

Comment: I have deleted the old one and created a new SSA. Still the same issue

Comment: Then only option is to check the ULS logs in detail.

Comment: 08/01/2019 14:19:18.59  w3wp.exe (0x0DF0)0x0D68 SharePoint Foundation 
CSOM ahjq1 High Exception occured in scope Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery.ctor. 
Exception=Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException: 
The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.     
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext ServiceContext)     
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.CreateQueryProxy(SPContext context)at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query..ctor(SPWeb web)

Comment: at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryServerStub.InvokeConstructor(XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeConstructorWithMonitoredScope(XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext) 
20e0f59e-d48b-b041-7f0d-fc57454afb27

Comment: how can i send logs to you?

Comment: add it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96892/discussion-between-dhruvil29-and-harris).

Answer (score 0):

Goto Central Administration
Application management
Manage Web Applications
Select the web application
Click on Service Connections
Ensure that the search application you configured is checked in this list.

Thanks to Development 4.0